# PayPal Billing Agreement: Does the inital payment count in the frequency?

Tags: paypal

I'm using NVP but I don't think the question is specific to any particular API and I'm not finding a definitive answer in the documentation or via search. Does the initial payment on a billing agreement count toward the billing frequency or not?

Example:
If I created a billing agreement with period=monthly, frequency=3, and initial payment=$25, is one billing cycle going to collect $100 (initial payment plus three additional payments) or $75 (initial payment is the first of three payments)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The initial payment is separate from the recurring payments, so in your example it would charge $25 right away as the initial payment, another $25 as the first recurring payment, and then 2 more $25 recurring charges for the total of $100.